# How to make the hydra output directory configurable from configuration?

Tags: fb-hydra

How to make the hydra output directory configurable from configuration?

Like, I'd like to be able to specify the directory that hydra dumps it's hydra.yaml to, instead of it being hardcoded to outputs.

I imagine one way to achieve this could be something like:

- have an option to instantiate hydra without dumping the config to outputs
- have a hydra method taht will dump the hydra config to a folder of our choice

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `hydra.output_subdir`.
From [the manual](https://hydra.cc/docs/tutorials/basic/running_your_app/working_directory#disabling-output-subdir).

> You can change the `.hydra` subdirectory name by overriding `hydra.output_subdir`. You can disable its creation by overriding `hydra.output_subdir` to `null`.